# Java Serversocket

Tags: java, sockets

I got a minor issue. I want to use serversockets to send over a list of players to a client. But for some reason when I try to run the application it will stop at when it reaches `socket = serverSocket.accept();`. I tried serval things on google but doesn't work.

```
package Serverside;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Hero;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Player;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 *
 * @author Tjidde Nieuwenhuizen
 */
public class ServerArenaOfLegends {
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static Socket socket;
    static ObjectOutputStream outStreamObj;
    static ObjectInputStream inStreamObj;
    static ArrayList<Player> playerList;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerArenaOfLegends sr = new ServerArenaOfLegends();
        sr.run();
    }
    private void run() {
        playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        Player p1;
        Hero hero = new Hero(2, null, 3);
        p1 = new Player(null, null, hero);
        playerList.add(p1);
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            outStreamObj = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {
                outStreamObj.writeObject(playerList);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try run a telnet to the server on port 5555 from your PC. Do you get the same behavior ?

Comment: It goes wrong before server can be started.

Comment: "It goes wrong" is not enough information. Please add Stacktraces, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The program will appear to hang.

Then on the command line run "telnet 127.0.0.1 5555"
The program will then print "DONE" and then end.

So [.accept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--) blocks until it gets data and this is the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: For some reason my client didn't send to the proper port, via telnet it worked instantly.